# PHP code is displayed incorrectly [ in one line ] EOL

Tags: php

When I try to upload a php file on my server I get a message: `"Parse error: ..."` I know what that means, but the problem is something else.

If I edit the file on my local server (I XAMPP installed on my computer) everything is fine.
But if I upload the same file online (Hosting at Godaddy) all code is displayed in one line. I have tested this by downloading it from server and then in Notepad++.

For example my code looks like this:

```
<?php
     //my comment 
     echo 'First';
     echo 'Second';
?>
```

But is displays:

```
<?php //my comment echo 'First'; echo 'Second';?>
```

So, now `//my comment` breaks all my code.

I can't find a solution for this. Please help.

Comment: Maybe UNIX / Windows EOL issues?

Comment: Use ascii / text mode when uploading the files with FTP

Comment: you can solve quickly this using /* coments */ but you need fix your End Of Line issue (configure your notepad++ to use the same EOL than your target system or use dos2unix/ unix2dos unix commands

Comment: Does your file have a .php extension?

Comment: @ Tiago Peczenyj, Yes this comment can be changed so, but, if my file have 500 line of code this looks ugly and I can't read it.

Comment: This is a homepage for a Wordpress template. Here is the code full code http://pastebin.com/4cLY3QzE
@Chibuzo, yes it have. It works on localhost.

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue but no error messages.  Attempting the ASCII transfer mode to see if that does anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an editor like `Notepad++` for editing your code.

There are two possibilities. Godaddy server you are having is on `Windows` and you are on a Unix based system. And the Other way around.

In short, `\r\n` breaks used in UNIX is not actually compatible with `\n` breaks used in Windows. So use an editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)  which has a preference to save with `\r\n` breaks by default.

**Edit:**

Try switching the transfer mode  from Binary to  ASCII as well in the FTP program you are using. Usually FTP softwares are supposed to cross support the text files on the host and client during the transfer.

**Edit 2**[ Thanks  @Wesley Murch ]

For easy switching of EOL(End of Line) Format : `Edit -> EOL Convertion -> Windows` Format

Comment: Also in NP++: `Alt -> Edit -> EOL Conversion`

Comment: Ah ,is that what ASCII mode is for? To convert certain kind of characters? I always wondered why there are these modes... learned something new today :)

Comment: for me too, it was a new thing... +1

Comment: @Wesley Murch, thank you. Saved me. Previously I have edited this file on another computer with Mac OS. After changing in Notepad++ `Edit -> EOL Convertion -> Windows Format`, all is OK. Thanks for all.

Comment: +1 Happened to me the same thing, I solved by switching off the "auto" FTP settings and making it ASCII in FileZilla. Funny thing it happened only on some files, and all of a sudden (had been using that host for months). Go figure.

Comment: For NotePad2  Open    File->Line Breaks ->Unix(LF)   and Save

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after moving to Git from Mercurial for VCS. If you are using Netbeans as your IDE there is a great plugin to help: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36810/show-and-change-line-endings